# How to calculate Relative Share in R

Tags: r

I was looking for relative share when total and sub-total given in the data, I need relative share on the basis of sub-total.

[I need % column value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8flXT.png)

Answer (score 0):

An option is

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Percent = case_when(!Group %in% c("Total", "Sub Total") ~
          100 * Points/Points[Group == "Sub Total"], TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

-output

```
#       Group Points  Percent
#1     Total    900       NA
#2 Sub Total    215       NA
#3         A     50 23.25581
#4         B     57 26.51163
#5         C     39 18.13953
#6         D     69 32.09302
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Group = c("Total", "Sub Total", "A", "B", "C", 
"D"), Points = c(900, 215, 50, 57, 39, 69)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```